# lista desplegable no muestra todos los datos de una bd

Tags: php, html, mysqli

me darian una manito? estoy practicando con php mysql y demas cosillas y tengo el siguiente problema, paso a explicar:

tengo 2 bd

categoria

-id

-categoria

articulos

-id

-id_categoria

-titulo

id_categoria de la base articulos se relaciona con el id de la base categoria

subi tres articulos de ejemplo a la bd articulos, dos estan relacionados con a un id de la bd categoria el restante a otro,

genero esta consulta(que seguramente esta mal por eso no hace lo que necesito)

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria INNER JOIN articulos ON articulos.id_categoria = categoria.id GROUP BY categoria.categoria ORDER BY categoria.categoria ASC";

$data = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

echo"<li class='toggle'>".$r['categoria']."

<ul class='ul'>

<li>".$r['titulo']."</li></ul></li>";

};

?>
```

y me resulta la primera imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veran en la segunda imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al pasar por sobre la palabra html (el id que tiene relacionado dos articulos) solo aparece uno, que idean me dan para poder hacer que aparezcan los dos

desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El error**

Lo que sucede es que en tu consulta estás obteniendo la lista de **productos** con su categoría, y al agrupar por categoría, solo obtendrás el primer producto.

**Lo que deberías hacer**

No necesitas obtener la lista de productos, sino la lista de categorías y posteriormente, la lista de productos de cada categoría.

**Solución**

Intenta la siguiente, a tu consulta SQL cámbialo por este:

```
SELECT id, categoria FROM categoria GROUP BY categoria.categoria ORDER BY categoria.categoria ASC
```

Posteriormente el código PHP hay que modificarlo para que obtenga los productos de cada categoría (ojo, vamos a crear otra QUERY, ahora tendremos 2):

```
# Obtenemos las categorías con el nuevo query y las almacenas en $data

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

    $articulos_query = "SELECT id, titulo FROM articulos WHERE id_categoria = " . $r['id'];
    $articulos = mysqli_query($cnx, $articulos_query);

    echo "<li class='toggle'>" . $r['categoria'] . "<ul class='ul'>";

    while ($art = mysqli_fetch_array($articulos)) {
        echo "<li>" . $art['titulo'] . "</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul></li>";
};
```

**Explicación**

El código PHP obtiene los artículos de cada categoría, ahora tienes dos loops, uno por cada categoría y uno por cada artículo de ésta.
En el primer loop se imprime el nombre del dropdown, y en el segundo por cada producto se imprime un elemento en la lista

Comment: muchas gracias **medina** era justo lo que estaba buscando hacer!!